# Dismiss notification in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

I've face some problem while chatting in different chat rooms. 
When you got highlighted, there is a little round marker above your gravatar. 
When clicking on it, you're brought to the highlights in (first to last).

But I'm using two or three computers and the problem is that dismissing on one computer does not dismiss on the others.

So what about making a system that :

1. Dismiss icons without linking to highlights
   -or-
2. Dismiss notifications on all computers when doing it on one.

Maybe the feature already exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the chat FAQ](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#notifications):

> When someone mentions *you*, a counter will appear on the avatar next to your input box, showing how often you were mentioned.
>
> http://or.sstatic.net/chat/Img/faq-reply-count.png?v=8568e30a8d8a
>
> Clicking on this number will highlight the messages that addressed you. **To remove the counter without highlighting the replies, enter a message in the chat, or simply press <kbd>esc</kbd>.**

Comment: Argh... I should really RTFM again :P